# How do I fix POST request 404 Bar Request Error

Tags: postman, http-post, backend

I would love a second pair of eyes on this because I can not figure out how to solve the error

My Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require("joi");

const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "first name is required"],
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: [false],
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "phone number is required"]
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [false],
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }
});

const Contact = new mongoose.model("Contact", ContactSchema);

const validateContact = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    first_name: Joi.string().min(4).max(50).required(),
    surname: Joi.string().min(4).max(50),
    phone: Joi.number().min(7).max(10000000000),
    email: Joi.string().email()
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};

module.exports = {
  validateContact,
  Contact,
};
```

My post route

```
const { validateContact, Contact } = require("../models/Contact");
const auth = require("../middlewares/auth");

const router = require("express").Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


router.post("/contact", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateContact(req.body);

  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: error.details[0].message });
  }

  const { first_name, surname, phone, email } = req.body;

  try {
    const newContact = new Contact({
      first_name,
      surname,
      phone,
      email,
      postedBy: req.user._id,
    });
    const result = await newContact.save();

    return res.status(201).json({ ...result._doc });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XfF8.png)

I tried
-checking request format

- that the field names were valid (double checked the spelling)
- Checked for spaces
- Verified there were no additional required fields that were not included in my input
- checked the validation rules

Comment: In the POST route you have `catch (error)` but you log `console.log(err)`. The problem in the screenshot is most likely caused by the Express server or the middleware.